# Set launcher reveal mode to Intellihide

Tags: 12.04, unity, configuration, unity-2d

Starting from Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), Unity stopped supporting the Intellihide reveal mode for the Unity launcher. However, Ubuntu Tweak can still change the settings so that it does Intellihide, and it works well (at least in Unity 2D) unless you open Appearance Preferences. This is what I have been using to set the mode to Intellihide.

I want to know, what are the commands (like using `gsettings`, etc.) that I can use to set Intellihide this way because then I won't need to install Ubuntu Tweak just to change the launcher settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gsettings command to tweak the hide mode of launcher would be:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode 2
```

Do note that this command will work **only** for Unity-2D and ***not*** for Unity-3D.

---

The supported parameters for this command and what they do:

```
0: Never hide; The launcher is always visible.
1: Auto hide; The launcher will disappear if it not actively used.
2: Intellihide; The launcher will disappear only if there is an active window over it.
```

Comment: Thanks! And is there any way to do it for 3D (just curious...)?

Comment: No, they removed the code for Intellihide in Unity-3D. So, it is not possible to do the same in Unity-3D. If you really want, you can possibly use an [unofficial Unity fork for Intellihide.](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-get-dodge-windows-and-minimize.html)