# Ubuntu 14.04 launcher intellihide

Tags: unity, autohide, launcher

I was wondering is there any way I can set my launcher to intellihide? For example just like "docky", which hides whenever there is a window obstructing the dock?

Thanks,
Nazir

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172505/set-launcher-reveal-mode-to-intellihide)

Answer (score 0):

You may have found the answer already but if you download the Unity Tweak Tool it has the option under the launcher tab.

Comment: Alt + F1 will show it again or pushing the monitor edge also.